# How use doctrine import filter as a strict?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I´m trying import a single table from a database with the next command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force InventBundle xml  --filter="invent"
```

but not work I get the next message:

> Table invent2 has no primary key. Doctrine does not support reverse
>   engineering from tables that don't have a primary key.

I can't delete `invet2`, but I need to import only invent table.

Any idea?

**Edit:**
The problem is filter doesn't use equals, and `invent` and `invent2` is founded for `filter="invet"`, but the only `invent2` is founded when use `filter="invent2"`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem as you. The **--filter** option does not seem to work (in my case, I am using multiple database connections, maybe that's why)

Here is how I solved it:

In your `app/config/config.yml` file you will have to add a "schema_filter".
Doctrine seems to use preg_match in this case, so you have to use a syntax like this, to match your table name:

schema_filter:`~^YourTableName$~`

**Note:** If you are using **Symfony4**, then your file of interest is `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

Here is the complete snippet:

```
// app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        schema_filter: ~^YourTableName$~
```